# I keep getting a "ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 3, saw 10"

Tags: read.csv

I keep getting a "ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 3 fields in line 3, saw 10" when i read my csv file that has a two rows of just informtaion before the data table starts. I have been trying to read the file so that I can delete those rows before I start to analyze the data
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvDJC.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emyxC.png)

I have tried .iloc as well .drop, they don't work as the error occurs even before I can delete the rows. I have even tried writing a function for it but it ends up deleting everything in it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer. Using the "skiprows" attribute of pd.read can help. I have attached a screenshot of my code. I hope it helps you if you are facing the same problems.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sFcg.png)